# ProcessBuilder not working

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am implementing the ProcessBuilder program that calls an another java program. However, I am getting class not found.

The program simply produces the following output:

> **Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld**
>
> **Program complete**

```
public class ProcessBuilderSample {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder broker = new ProcessBuilder("java.exe", "-cp",
                "F:\\LunaWorkspace\\ProcessBuilderTest\\bin" ,"com\\hello\\HelloWorld");  

            Process runBroker = broker.start();                     

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(runBroker.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(runBroker.getErrorStream()));

        String str=null;

        while((str=reader.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(str);
        }

        while((str=reader1.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(str);
        }

            runBroker.waitFor();

            System.out.println("Program complete");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the java program that I would like to execute. This program produce Hello World as output.

```
package com.hello;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String arg[]){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Now I am using:

ProcessBuilder broker = new ProcessBuilder("java.exe", "-cp",
                    "F:\LunaWorkspace\ProcessBuilderTest\bin" ,"com\hello\HelloWorld");

This command works on command prompt, but not working with processbuilder.

**EDIT:**

Full classpath:

ProcessBuilderSample.class:

> F:\LunaWorkspace\ProcessBuilderExample\bin\com\sample

HelloWorld.class:

> F:\LunaWorkspace\ProcessBuilderTest\bin\com\hello Thanks!!

Comment: call `runBroker.getErrorStream()` and read the error you got

Comment: Actually I want to execute it

Comment: cool will delete the comment :) now verify  that you can run that command you are passing to Process builder from command line (make sure you are trying to execute from the same place you are executing ProcessBuilderSample

Comment: yeah, command is working from the command prompt but from processbuilder. Error produced by ProcessBuilder, Error: Could not find or load main class com\hello\HelloWorld

Comment: are you compiling this from scratch every time? remove your class files and try again. you will see you have unresolved symbol runBroker

Comment: Did you compile HelloWorld.java first using javac and then specify the path where the HelloWorld.class file exists.

Comment: @Mil4n sorry i have edited my code.

Comment: @svasa yes, I have specified the bin directory, where .class is located.

Comment: can you tell what is the full path of your class file?

Comment: @svasa edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to fix you HelloWorld class name in constructing your process builder:

`"com\\hello\\HelloWorld"` -> `"com.hello.HelloWorld"`